# Get and format system time with SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

How do I get current Marketing Cloud system time,
usng SSJS on a cloud page.
This is the format I need:

> 11/8/2018 14:16:54

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

@Tove try like this

```
      <script runat="server">
     Platform.Load('Core','1');

      var date= Now();

     var d = new Date(date); 

   Write(d);
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but in this case I don't want to use any ampscript, just ssjs.

Comment: @Tove Try with mixing Ampscript and ssjs

Comment: Wow this works just fine and is incredible simple and brief